# Filter lat-lon points using shapefile in R

Tags: r, filter, shapefile

I am trying to filter lat-lon points of tropical cyclones using a shapefile:

1. [Link to shapefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qg0c5bakdtnertg/Bicol_Region.zip?dl=0)

I am doing a similar problem from a previous post:

[Filter TC tracks (lat-lon points) over a specified gridbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508161/filter-tc-tracks-lat-lon-points-over-a-specified-gridbox)

But in this case, I am using an irregular shapefile (not a box).

I wanted to filter only the points with the same identifier (the "SN" column in the sample data below) that passed over a shapefile. So, only unique TCs will be filtered.

Here's a subset of the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(SN = c(200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 
200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 200608L, 
200610L, 200610L, 200610L, 200612L, 200612L, 200612L, 200612L, 
200612L, 200612L, 200612L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 
200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 
200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 
200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 
200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L, 200709L), CY = c(8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), Year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L), Month = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), Day = c(9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L), Hour = c(0L, 
6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 
6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 
0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 
12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L), Lat = c(23.7, 24.7, 
25.3, 25.9, 26.4, 27, 27.2, 27.4, 27.7, 28.1, 28.5, 28.9, 22.8, 
22.9, 22.4, 18.7, 19.8, 20.2, 21, 22.4, 23.9, 26.9, 17.4, 17, 
16.7, 16.6, 16.5, 16.4, 16.3, 16.2, 16, 15.8, 15.5, 15.6, 15.9, 
16.1, 16.6, 17.2, 17.9, 18.7, 19.4, 20.2, 21, 21.9, 22.7, 23.4, 
24, 24.4, 24.8, 25.2, 25.6, 26), Lon = c(128.4, 126.9, 125.3, 
123.9, 122.5, 121.1, 119.9, 118.7, 117.4, 115.8, 115, 114.4, 
119.8, 118.6, 117.7, 131.3, 132.4, 133.9, 135.6, 137.2, 139.1, 
140.4, 135.4, 135.2, 134.8, 134.3, 133.7, 133, 132.3, 131.5, 
130.7, 129.9, 129.2, 128.5, 128, 127.6, 127.1, 126.6, 126.1, 
125.6, 124.8, 124.2, 123.5, 122.8, 122, 121.2, 119.9, 119.4, 
119, 118.6, 118.3, 118)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))
```

[Full link of data is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1i5003g4jekdvg/JTWC.csv?dl=0)

Expected results:

My expected results are similar to the link above. Two additional columns in the csv file that indicates whether the TCs are within the shapefile. 
Each TC has a unique identifier: the SN column. So if the lat-lon points with the same SN number are within the shapefile, they are flagged as TRUE (all lat-lon points with the same SN number).

```
dat[SN %in% dat[inBounds == TRUE, unique(SN)], passesThroughBox := T ]
dat[is.na(passesThroughBox), passesThroughBox := F]
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this in R?

Sincerely,
Lyndz

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: look at `library(sf)`, it has all the functions you need for geometric calculations.

Comment: hi psychOle, I have updated my post. My expected result is a csv file with columns indicating whether the lat-lon points are within the boundaries of the shapefile.

Comment: Why are you expecting two columns as an output? (and a quick plot seems to show that none of the points in your data go over the shape - this is a subset of your real data set, yes?)

Comment: What if the line formed by the data goes over the shape, but the points at each end don't? Do you want to flag that as intersecting the shape?

Comment: @Spacedman. Thank you for pointing this out. It should be "two additional columns". I updated my post and gave the link for the full data. I just want to extract the whole TCs track that passed through the shapefile. No need to flag those as intersecting because they are "part" of the whole TC track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best sample data, since not one observation seems to pass through  the bbox of the shapefile..
Nevertheless, her's my go at the problem..

```
library( tidyverse )
library( sf )
```

### sf and tidyverse solution

```
#first, get the boundaries of the shapefile
bbox <- read_sf(dsn = "./Bicol_Region/Bicol_region.shp") %>% st_bbox()

#      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
# 122.29929  11.71056 124.42607  14.50061 


dat %>% 
  #check if measurement is withing boundaries (yes, or not (no))
  mutate( passes_through_box = ifelse( Lat >= bbox[2] & Lat <= bbox[4] & Lon >= bbox[1] & Lon <= bbox[3], "yes", "no" ) ) %>%
  #group by SN
  group_by( SN ) %>%
  #check if any value of 'passes_through_box' in a group is "yes", if so 'yes', else 'no'
  mutate( passes_through_box_anyime = ifelse( any( passes_through_box == "yes"), "yes", "no" ) )

# # A tibble: 52 x 10
# # Groups:   SN [4]
#       SN    CY  Year Month   Day  Hour   Lat   Lon passes_through_box passes_through_box_anyime
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <chr>                    
# 1 200608     8  2006     8     9     0  23.7  128. no                 no                       
# 2 200608     8  2006     8     9     6  24.7  127. no                 no                       
# 3 200608     8  2006     8     9    12  25.3  125. no                 no                       
# 4 200608     8  2006     8     9    18  25.9  124. no                 no                       
# 5 200608     8  2006     8    10     0  26.4  122. no                 no                       
# 6 200608     8  2006     8    10     6  27    121. no                 no
```

### all sf solution

```
library( tidyverse )
library( sf )

#first, get the boundaries of the shapefile
bbox <- read_sf(dsn = "./Bicol_Region/Bicol_region.shp") %>% st_bbox() %>% st_as_sfc( crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

#      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
# 122.29929  11.71056 124.42607  14.50061 

#create aspatial data.frame
spdf <- st_as_sf( x = dat,
                  coords = c("Lon", "Lat"),
                  crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

spdf %>% 
  #check if a line the spatial df intersecgt with the defined boundary-box
  mutate( passes_through_box = as.numeric( st_intersects(spdf, bbox) ) ) %>%
  group_by( SN ) %>%
  mutate( passes_through_box_anyime = ifelse( any( passes_through_box == 1), "yes", "no" ) )
```

### for completeness sake, another sf-approach

```
library( tidyverse )
library( sf )

#first, get the boundaries of the shapefile and create a box
bbox <- read_sf(dsn = "./Bicol_Region/Bicol_region.shp") %>% st_bbox() %>% st_as_sfc( crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

#create a spatial points data.frame using the sample data provided
spdf <- st_as_sf( x = dat,
                  coords = c("Lon", "Lat"),
                  crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" )

#create a spatial lines data.frame, bases on lat-lon groupes by SN
sldf <- spdf %>%
  group_by( SN ) %>%
  summarise( m = mean( Year ) ) %>%
  st_cast( "LINESTRING" ) %>%
  select( -m )

#let's see the printed results
library(mapview)
mapview( list(bbox, sldf) )
```

[image]

```
#any intersections? ... #nope, no intersections
st_intersects( bbox, sldf )

# although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersects assumes that they are planar
# Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate was `intersects'
# 1: (empty)
```

Comment: @Lyndz I updated my answer with another approach (also as practice for myself ;-), and for future reference )..